Thymeleaf about th:block statement
I'm trying to use th:block to make table more specific to analyze my data..
i was trying
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>something</tr>
       <th>something2</tr>
       <th>something3</tr>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th:block th:if="${not #maps.isEmpty(result)}" th:each="firstEntry : ${result}">
           <th:block th:if="${firstEntryStat.count == 0}">
              <tr>
           </th:block>

           <td th:text="${firstEntry.value}"></td>

           <th:block th:if="${firstEntryStat.count == 0}">
              </tr>
           </th:block>
           
        </th:block>
   </tbody>
</table>

i attempted to make this kind of table (at the end of the post)
but it ends with the error which is

The element type "th:block" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
"</th:block>"

so i tried another way,
 <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>something</tr>
           <th>something2</tr>
           <th>something3</tr>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th:block th:if="${not #maps.isEmpty(result)}" th:each="firstEntry : ${result}">
             <tr th:if="${firstEntryStat.count == 0}">

               <td th:text="${firstEntry.value}"></td>

             </tr th:if="${firstEntryStat.count == 0}">
               
            </th:block>
       </tbody>
    </table>

However, it produced the error like

The end-tag for element type "tr" must end with a '>' delimiter.

is there any way to make datatable like the picture above?
My map data has structure like
Maps< String , Maps< String, Maps< String, Long>>> result = new HashMap<>();

result = {
  "First": {
    "time": {
      "now": "",
      "past": "",
      "future": ""
    },
    "sleifj": {
      "now": "",
      "past": "",
      "future": ""
    }
  },
  "Second": {
    "time": {
      "now": "",
      "past": "",
      "future": ""
    },
    "sleifj": {
      "now": "",
      "past": "",
      "future": ""
    }
  }
}

===================================================================
Additional Data Info
My map data looks like
First
  - time
        - now : slejflesf
        - past : lsijefleisf
        - future : lsajiefeasf
  - sleifj 
        - now : slejflesf
        - past : lsijefleisf
        - future : lsajiefeasf
Second
  - time
        - now : slejflesf
        - past : lsijefleisf
        - future : lsajiefeasf
  - sleifj 
        - now : slejflesf
        - past : lsijefleisf
        - future : lsajiefeasf




------------------------------------------------------
  Map Name  |  Sub Name  |  Now  |  Past  |  Future  |
------------------------------------------------------
  First     |    time    | asfas | lsefa  | saeflkjle|
            ------------------------------------------
            |    sleifj  | dsff  | sfesf  | sefasefa |
------------------------------------------------------
  Second    |    time    | asfas | lsefa  | saeflkjle|
            ------------------------------------------
            |    sleifj  | dsff  | sfesf  | sefasefa |
------------------------------------------------------


Can you add an example of what you want the html to look like? And what the data is in your map.

@Metroids I added an example above how it looks like

Please [edit] your question to include a code example of your data structure. It's unclear what result actually looks like or how it's supposed to map to the desired HTML table result

@Phil I posted my Map structure... is it clear now?

It would greatly help if you could express it with some data, eg Map.of("somestring", Map.of(...

@Phil I  don't clearly understand your meaning for Map.of... I tried to put on the data below Statement, is it the data what you want??

Yes, that's better. Thanks for updating

In your first example you'r missing a </tr> between the 2 </th:block> tags aswel as you'r trying to nest 2 table rows which is not advisable.
The second example stil has the same problems but for this I don't think you can use th:if on a closing tag.
Looking at the ASCII mockup you've written what you'd probably want to do is just leave the first <td> element empty on any item in the submap that is not the first. (see mock code below)
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Map Name</th>
            <th>Sub Name</th>
            <th>Now</th>
            <th>Past</th>
            <th>Future</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="mapNameItem : ${result}">
            <tr th:each="subMapItem : ${mapNameItem}">
                <td th:if="subMapItemStat.count == 0" th:text="mapNameItem.key" />
                <td th:if="subMapItemStat.count != 0" />
                
                <td th:text="subMapItem.key" />
                <td th:text="subMapItem.get('now')" />
                <td th:text="subMapItem.get('past')" />
                <td th:text="subMapItem.get('feature')" />
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
</table>

Potentially you'd want to move the outermost th:each on the th:block to the tbody instead depending on your formatting needs.

damn,,,, y I didn't think put th:if in  tag.... It helped me to make the column what I wanted! Thx for all guys' efforts!
